# Questions about validating user input in Objective-C, number vs string

Tags: objective-c, c, numbers, user-input

Why 'exactly' does this code loop endlessly if you enter a non number character?

The first question comes about because I want to learn good defensive coding. Does anyone know a good way to check user input? My google-fu failed me. Some people seemed to be of the opinion that if I specify `%f` in `scanf` that I am 'demanding' a `float`; I verified this, in a way, by printing the value of `userInput`. In fact, if I comment out the `do while` loop, there is 'no problem' with the execution of the code. It assigns a `0` to `userInput` and goes about its business.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    float userInput;
    float result;

    NSLog(@"3X^3 -5x^2 + 6");

    do {
        NSLog(@"What is x?");
        scanf("%f", &userInput);
        NSLog(@"userInput = %f", userInput);
    } while(userInput == 0);

    result = 3 * (userInput * userInput * userInput) - 5 * (userInput * userInput) + 6;
    NSLog(@"the result is: %f", result);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a checkmark to gavinb's reponse, if it was "great". That way future responders will be encouraged to respond to your questions.

Comment: thank you, i was trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really nothing to do with Objective-C or Cocoa.  The issue is simply to do with the use of the standard C library function `scanf`, and handling the error condition. From the `scanf` manpage, describing the return code:

> Zero indicates that, although there was input available, no conversions were assigned; typically this is due to an invalid input character, such as an alphabetic character for a `%d' conversion.

A valid numeric input can be parsed by `scanf` with the `%f` specifier, so that obviously works as expected.  But if you enter in a non-numeric character, `scanf` cannot convert this to a float, and *leaves the text in the buffer of `stdin`*.  Since the code is not checking the return code from `scanf`, and only testing if `userInput` is non-zero, the loop will never exit, as `userInput` happens to start at `0.0`, and will never be updated as `scanf` will not pull the non-numeric characters out of the `stdin` buffer.  So that is why your code runs in an infinite loop.

If you had initialized `userInput` to a non-zero value, that would fix the problem one way, as non-numeric input would cause `scanf` to fail and the `while` condition would be triggered.  But a better fix would be to check the return code of `scanf`.  If it is zero, print an error message, and do a `fpurge(stdin)` to clear out the invalid input before you loop around again, like this:

```
int rc = scanf("%f", &userInput);
if (rc == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid input, try again.");
    fpurge(stdin);
}
```

So this is the plain C approach to input and parsing.  The bottom line for defensive coding is that you should always check the return code!

As Chris mentions, for an actual Cocoa application, you would want to look at `NSNumberFormatter` and the like, but then you would presumably be taking input from widgets rather than file streams, so the code would be quite different to the above.

Comment: Thank you! that explanation is great. i thought that checking userInput was enough of a check, but that clarifies it very well.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to validate user input in Cocoa is to use an instance of an appropriate subclass of NSFormatter, in this case something like NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: so, do i have to create an NSString and pass that to the formatter  (numberFromString)?

Comment: Keep in mind that the user is entering a string already. What you're asking is basically "Should I get a string from the user, use C to turn it into a number, turn that back into a string, and pass it to my formatter?" The answer to that is no. Instead, get a string from the user, pass it to your formatter, and get a number back.